# AWS CLI giving InvalidClientTokenId error when Ansible is running well

Tags: ansible, boto3, aws-cli

I have the following set-up:

1. A script `updatecreds.py` runs, which updates AWS credentials in my Ansible creds file using STS.
2. Now, I took those creds to run AWS-related tasks in Ansible, and they run smoothly. But, the CLI commands give me an error.
3. When I use the same credentials in the `~/.aws/config` file, I get the following error when executing CLI commands: `A client error (InvalidClientTokenId) occurred when calling the ListAccessKeys operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

As some of my Ansible tasks run shell commands which are AWS cli commands, this behaviour is messing with my Ansible run too.

Why is AWS behaving so weirdly?  Or did I do something wrong here?

PS : My `~/.aws/config` looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<>
aws_secret_access_key=<>
aws_session_token=<>
region=us-east-1
```

Comment: Show the format of your `~/.aws/config` (mask actual credentials).

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Updated my question

Comment: Try to duplicate `aws_session_token=` with `aws_security_token=` and same token value.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov You're a genius.  And I'm confused :/ . `SessionToken` used to work!  Pl add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a confusion in `session`/`security` terms, see [this issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2988).

To make both `boto` and `aws cli` work correctly, duplicate them:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=KEY
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET
aws_session_token=TOKEN
aws_security_token=TOKEN
region=REGION
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without
   aws_session_token=<>

Mine works fine with only aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in ~/.aws.credentials

Comment: cause you're not using STS creds :)